# How to detect change of language in I.E 11 with ngx-translate translate service

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-11, ngx-translate

I am trying to internationalize my application by using ngx-translate and i am able to translate the labels and everything using ngx-translate translate service and it is working fine as expected in chrome it detects the language and fallbacks to particular json.

But when it comes to I.E 11 it is not getting done any how and it is not accepting any language and by default it is giving en only. I changed the language from internet options> language > set language preference > chinese (move to top) and then refresh.

Here is my code which i am doing.

Here is my code :

```
 translateService.addLangs(['en_gb', 'zh', 'en']);
    translateService.setDefaultLang('en');

    let browserLang = translateService.currentLang; 
    // even i have used this.translateService.getBrowserlang() also but dint worked for I.E
    browserLang = navigator.language;
    if (browserLang.indexOf('-') !== -1) {
      browserLang = browserLang.split('-')[0];
    }
    console.log('Languagecheck', browserLang);
    translateService.use(browserLang.match(/en|zh|en_gb/) ? browserLang : 'en');
```

and somewhere i have tried this also

```
   let m;
    let n;
    const isIEOrEdge = /msie\s|trident\/|edge\//i.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
    if ( isIEOrEdge ) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://ajaxhttpheaders.appspot.com',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success(headers) {
        let language = headers['Accept-Language'];
        m = language.split(',');
        n = m[0].toString();
        if (m[0].indexOf('-')) {
          m[0] = m[0].split('-');
          n = m[0][0].toString();
        }
        console.log(typeof(n));

    }
});
  setTimeout(() => {
  this.useLanguage(n);
}, 3000);

} else {
    let browserLang = navigator.language;
    if (browserLang.indexOf('-') !== -1) {
      browserLang = browserLang.split('-')[0];
    }
    this.useLanguage(browserLang);
  }
  }

  useLanguage(language: string) {
    console.log('Language called:', language);
   // this.data.addNewTabWithCanvas(language);
    this.translateService.use(language);
  }
```

But no luck. Please help me out because if it is not done for I.E it will be spill over .

thanks in advance

It should translate according to language change

Comment: any one can help on this

Comment: Have you used F12 dev tools to check if there's any error in console in IE? You could debug your code using F12 dev tools first. Besides, you could refer to the [official demo](https://stackblitz.com/github/ngx-translate/example) of ngx-translate. I test it in IE and it can translate well.

Comment: in that example it is getting done by an event not on initial load.But my application is something whose text change according to browser language

Comment: It could be better if you provide [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/). So that we can have a better understanding of the issue and can test it in our sides. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I will for sure.. in my next comment i will attach it

Comment: Hi Mayank, have you solved the issue? If you have solved the issue then you could try to post the answer and mark it as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.